# Find missing record between date range

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

At the end of an enormous stored procedure (in SQL Server), I've created two CTE. One with some date ranges (with 6 month intervals) and one with some records. 
Let's assume i have date ranges on table B from 2020-01-01 to 2010-01-01 (with 6 months intervals)

```
Start        End
----------------------
2020-01-01 | 2020-07-01
...     ...
other years here
...     ...
2010-01-01 | 2010-07-01
```

and on table A this situation:

```
Name     Date
-----------------
John    2020-01-01
John    2019-01-01
John    2018-07-01
...     ...
Rob     2020-01-01
Rob     2019-07-01
Rob     2018-07-01
...     ...
```

I'm trying to generate a recordset like this:

```
Name   MissingDate
-----------------
John    2019-07-01
...     ...
John    2010-01-01

Rob     2019-01-01
...     ...
Rob     2010-01-01
```

I've got the flu and I barely know who I am at this moment, I hope it was clear and if anyone could help me with this I would really appreciate it.

Comment: I'm lost.  What are the rules for generating the record set you want?

Comment: Not to be rude, but you realise your closing statement could easily be read to be you're saying *"I'm ill at the moment, so can't work; could someone do this for me please?"* At least show us the SQL you have and explain why it isn't working. Also, your results aren't don't explain what you're actually after at all I'm afraid.

Comment: @Larnu I'm not saying I can't work, I already did almost 500 lines of t-sql, i know exactly how to resolve this on c# but I'm asking for help to do this on SQlServer, because i'm not feeling quite right and i can't think good right now. If someone can help it's ok, if nobody can help it's ok either. I'm not asking to do my job, i'm asking the community to help me out find a way to do it in SQLServer, sorry if 
I badly explained myself, i didn't want to

Comment: Which is why i asked if you show us where you go to, and where what you have isn't working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want missing dates (which appear to be by month), then generate all available dates and take out the ones you have.

```
with cte as (
      select start, end
      from dateranges
      union all
      select dateadd(month, 1, start), end
      from cte
      where start < end
    )
select n.name, cte.start
from cte cross join
     (select distinct name from tablea) n left join
     tablea a
     on a.date = cte.start and a.name = n.name
where a.date is null;
```

Comment: Thanks, that was exactly what i was trying to do, I didn't realize that i could use cross join too! I had to modified it anyway but it was nearly to my need. Really thank you!